# How to wait until CSS is loaded/rendered without ExtractTextPlugin

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, leaflet

I'm looking for a way to run JS after CSS has been applied to the current document when using Webpack. In production this works because the ExtractTextPlugin makes sure that the CSS is injected in the head and I can use document.ready to achieve this behavior. In debug mode I use the dev server and hot reloading and there it doesn't work although I require the CSS files before calling the JS code which doesn't work as expected.

The background: I'm using a Leaflet map which has a 100% width set via CSS. When setting the map center location via JS, the map still has a width of 0px because the whole CSS is not loaded. This way the center location is very wrong when the width is set afterwards. When using a timeout of 1s or so, it works fine but this can't be the solution...

Is there a way how I can webpack tell to wait for the CSS module to be loaded or any other solution so that I can use hot reloading and make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why to you don't include you script in the end of your page ? like that it will wait that your page is loading with all the other script and css before play it.

Comment: Like I said, I want to use the dev server with hot reloading. This way, both the script and CSS is delivered via the script tag at the end of the page. When I use the document.ready approach to get the element's actual width there, it still says 0 because the CSS is not injected yet at this point. The same happens with require's callback handler as I just tried to solve it this way.

Comment: Put your JS code inside `window.onload = function() {
   // here
};`

Comment: You're absolutely right... document.ready only waits for the HTML to be loaded while window.onload waits for CSS as well. If you submit this as the answer, I'll mark it accordingly. Thanks a lot!